# Finding the outer borders from the list of random coordinates

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, openlayers, math

I've a huge list (60 000+) of coordinates and I haven't found a way for recognizing the outer borders.

The list of coordinates are quite random, but they're defining some really specific area.

I should be able to draw an area by using that list by using OpenLayers, so they also should in order.

This seemed to be relatively easy nut to break but has proven to be quite challenging.

What might be the best approach for this problem?

- Heikki

Comment: What's the 'outer border' here? Do you want the 'convex hull' (google it) or just the bounding box?

Comment: Convex hull is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for a [convex hull](http://python.net/~gherman/convexhull.html)?

Comment: @Heikki Mustonen: Note that some of the comments on the ActiveState script you linked to in your own answer may apply to the code linked to in this one (which is essentially the same thing by the same author).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the bounding box, it's easy enough:

```
min_x = MAX_INT;
min_y = MAX_INT;
max_x = MIN_INT;
max_y = MIN_INT;

for p in points:
  if p.x < min_x then min_x = p.x;
  if p.y < min_y then min_y = p.y;
  if p.x > max_x then max_x = p.x;
  if p.y > max_y then max_y = p.x;
```

If there's no easy equivalent of MAX_INT and MIN_INT on your platform, just pick the first one in the list. It's possibly less 'pretty' code, but it is also possibly faster by a meaningless amount.

Of course, if your data were ordered in some significant way, you might be able to do something more clever than iterating over 60k items and performing 240k comparisons. (Keeping in mind that ordering 60k points in some significant way just for this may not pay for itself.)

Comment: That's a good idea, but the resolution of the box is not high enough. We need to be able to define a multidimensional area.

Answer (score 1):

Convex hull is the subject what I've been looking for. I found a really nice script from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66527-finding-the-convex-hull-of-a-set-of-2d-points/.

Many thanks for all participants!